# Eigen: Fast average angle between vector3ds

Tags: c++, geometry, eigen, angle, eigen3

I'm using the Eigen library to calculate the average angle between two vectors of Vector3ds. There has to be a faster way than to try every combination "by hand"?

```
double average_angle(const std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>& v1, const std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>& v2)
{
    double result = 0;
    for (const auto& v1_entry : v1)
    {
        for (const auto& v2_entry : v2)
        {
            result += acos(v1_entry.dot(v2_entry));
        }
    }
    const auto item_count = v1.size() * v2.size();
    return result / item_count;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to solve? For the case where all vectors in `v1` are "similar" and the same for `v2` perhaps the angle between the average vectors works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately they can be quite different, so that won't work reliably.

Comment: I also tried averaging all the dot products together and taking the acos of that. That doesn't seem to work, though.

Comment: The result depends a lot on the given vectors. In some weird cases you'll get absurd results. That's why I think you should tell us your "real" problem.

Answer (score 3):

A more elegant version is:

```
Matrix3Xd::Map M1(v1[0].data(), 3, v1.size();
Matrix3Xd::Map M2(v2[0].data(), 3, v2.size();
return (M1.transpose() * M2).diagonal().array().acos().mean();
```

but don't expect it to be faster as this will boils down to the same code.